# Make graph from Loki logs in Grafana

Tags: grafana, dashboard, grafana-loki

I add Loki as Grafana data source and get logs from docker app

App produce this type of log

`Application - GET /programs/statement fromDate=2023-08-01&toDate=2023-08-31 200 OK 11 ms`

I need graph there i can see count of this type of records and min and max ms

I found i can count number of records by using sum but i can't figured out how to make graph with ms

Make Grafana dashboard where I can see in graph count of records and min and max ms of record

Comment: To count these message you probably should use `count_over_time`, and not `sum`.

Comment: Hello @markalex. Thanks for answer. I need to figure out how to extract value in ms from messages ( 11 ms) and make graf with this values. Is it possible?

Comment: Use regexp parser https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#regular-expression